# Limit of $(1+u^{1/n})^n$ as $n\to\infty$ in $p$-adic topology.

Tags: analysis, p-adic-number-theory, nonarchimedian-analysis

I am wondering that if the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+u^{1/n})^n$ is known to have a closed form.

Also I am wondering what if we take limit in $p$-adic world? In this case, I am mostly interested in the case when $u$ is a $p$-adic unit.

Comment: Please add more thoughts and context. Besides starting with the example $u=1$, have you thought about what $u^{1/n}$ is supposed to mean to begin with, given that we often have $n$ different $n$-th roots?

Comment: And indeed, $u$ may well have no $n$-th roots at all.

Comment: There is an exponential function, described by the usual series, but in the $p$-adic world, its domain of convergence is inconveniently small.